# How to configure authentication for Spark Connect?

Tags: python, authentication, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, grpc-python

I recently discovered the [Spark Connect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html) new feature in Spark 3.4. I have tested it on a YARN cluster and it works well! However, anyone can access my Spark Connect server and run jobs with my user. **Is it possible to configure authentication for Spark Connect?** A simple password, or the combination of an user name and a password.

I search something like:

- Server side

```bash
./sbin/start-connect-server.sh \
--jars jars/spark-connect_2.12-3.4.1.jar \
--master yarn --name SparkConnectTest \
--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive \
--conf password=mysuperpassword
```

- Client side

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://localhost").conf("password", "mysuperpassword").getOrCreate()
```

The official [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html#client-application-authentication) says:

> While Spark Connect does not have built-in authentication, it is designed to work seamlessly with your existing authentication infrastructure. Its gRPC HTTP/2 interface allows for the use of authenticating proxies, which makes it possible to secure Spark Connect without having to implement authentication logic in Spark directly.

But I don't know how to configure gRPC with Spark Connect.

- Python 3.7.6
- PySpark 3.4.1
- Hadoop 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

### gRPC Proxy

proxying gRPC traffic: gRPC client -> APISIX -> gRPC/gRPCS server

> https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/grpc-proxy/

Maybe can help you.

--------------2023-11-02 updated-------------------------

I use a simpel gRPC example and proxy gRPC with apisix。

```
package user; 

service UserService{
  rpc getUserInfo(UserRequest) returns (UserResponse);
}

message UserRequest{
  string id = 1;
}

message UserResponse{
  string id = 1;
  int32 phoneNumber = 2; 
  string email = 3; 
  int32 serialNumber = 4; 
}
```

use apisix admin API to add route and auth.

```
# add route
curl http://127.0.0.1:30918/apisix/admin/routes/1 -H 'X-API-KEY: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1' -X PUT -d '
{
    "methods": ["POST", "GET"],
    "uri": "/user.UserService/getUserInfo",
    "upstream": {
        "scheme": "grpc",
        "type": "roundrobin",
        "nodes": {
            "172.28.208.1:5001": 1
        }
    }
}'

# add key-auth info
curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:30918/apisix/admin/consumers" -H 'X-API-KEY: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1' -X PUT -d '
{
  "username": "tom",
  "plugins": {
    "key-auth": {
      "key": "secret-key"
    }
  }
}'

# add key-auth plugin to route
curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:30918/apisix/admin/routes/1" -X PATCH -H 'X-API-KEY: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1' -d '
{
  "plugins": {
    "key-auth": {}
  }
}'
```

when I use client call service without apikey or wrong value:

```
Please input user id: 1
Please input user id: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: HTTP status code 401
invalid content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
headers: Metadata(:status=401,date=Wed, 01 Nov 2023 03:39:18 GMT,content-type=text/plain; charset=utf-8,server=APISIX/3.6.0)
DATA-----------------------------
{"message":"Missing API key found in request"}

    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:222)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:203)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:132)
    at com.meritdata.grpc.proto.UserServiceGrpc$UserServiceBlockingStub.getUserInfo(UserServiceGrpc.java:358)
    at com.meritdata.grpc.client.ClientApp.getUserInfo(ClientApp.java:46)
    at com.meritdata.grpc.client.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:23)
```

spark connect gRPC proxy coming soon on.

-----------------Last updated------------------

Add spark connect route:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:30918/apisix/admin/routes/spark-connect -H 'X-API-KEY: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1' -X PUT -d '
{
    "methods": ["POST", "GET"],
    "uri": "/spark.connect.SparkConnectService/*",
    "upstream": {
        "scheme": "grpc",
        "type": "roundrobin",
        "nodes": {
            "10.43.105.147:15002": 1
        }
    },
    "plugins": {
        "key-auth": {}
    }
}'
```

use pyspark in python code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://172.28.220.144:30981/;apikey=secret-key").getOrCreate()
...
spark.stop()
```

When there is no apiKey provided or an incorrect value is used during the connection, an error will be reported.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://172.28.220.144:30981/;apikey=secret-key1").getOrCreate()
E1102 14:17:30.511000000 16764 src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_parser.cc:999] Error parsing 'content-type' metadata: invalid value
...\Miniconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\connect\session.py:185: UserWarning: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Stream removed"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"Stream removed", grpc_status:2, created_time:"2023-11-02T06:17:30.5118727+00:00"}"
>
  warnings.warn(str(e))
E1102 14:17:30.546000000 16764 src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_parser.cc:999] Error parsing 'content-type' metadata: invalid value
...Miniconda3\envs\python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\connect\session.py:185: UserWarning: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Stream removed"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2023-11-02T06:17:30.5470989+00:00", grpc_status:2, grpc_message:"Stream removed"}"
>
  warnings.warn(str(e))
```

But the error message is not specific, you can use the Wireshark tool to inspect the returned value.

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.28.220.144, Dst: 172.28.208.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 30981, Dst Port: 59795, Seq: 207, Ack: 837, Len: 77
HyperText Transfer Protocol 2
    Stream: HEADERS, Stream ID: 3, Length 68, 401 Unauthorized
        Length: 68
        Type: HEADERS (1)
        Flags: 0x04, End Headers
        0... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Reserved: 0x0
        .000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 = Stream Identifier: 3
        [Pad Length: 0]
        Header Block Fragment: 48033430316197df3dbf4a004a693f75040132a01ab8d3b7196d4c5a37ff5f92497ca58a…
        [Header Length: 130]
        [Header Count: 4]
        Header: :status: 401 Unauthorized
        Header: date: Thu, 02 Nov 2023 04:47:35 GMT
        Header: content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
        Header: server: APISIX/3.6.0
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it, instead of just posting a list of techniques

Comment: As stated in the official documentation, it is necessary to have a proxy for authentication. Recently, I have been researching how to add authentication to Spark Connect, so that it is not accessible to anyone. This seems to be the only possible solution I have found during my search, but it still needs to be validated. I am sharing this in advance to see if anyone else has already found a solution. I hope everyone can contribute their own ideas instead of waiting for others, as the official documentation does not provide a specific solution.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your answer by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35182817)

Comment: The validation result has been updated.